# Converting from int16 to float32 using NEON intrinsics

Tags: c, intrinsics, neon

I have a C program where I need to convert an array of int16_t values to float values.

My current program uses the following:

```
void conversion(int16_t *int16_arr, float *float_arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        float_arr[i] = int16_arr[i];
    }
}
```

Given that the arrays may be of size 64 or 128, and this function may be called a large amount of times, is it possible to use NEON intrinsics to speed it up? And if so, how?

Comment: I'd expect mainstream compilers to vectorize that for you, if you tell them they can use NEON, like clang and GCC do: https://godbolt.org/z/od5Wsnqvd  Of course, it might be better to combine this with later work on the same array since it's fairly.  If you read the float array a lot of times, it might be worth it to do a pass over the data just converting, otherwise convert on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

The advice in Peter's comment is definitely right, but also, you can probably achieve better performance than the compiler if that's worth your effort.

If you know the array is either 64 or 128 long, then in your implementation you won't need to implement 'tail' code coping with array sizes that don't fit perfectly into vectors.

But more than that, loop unrolling will allow you to improve performance, where you load multiple vectors into the array in each loop, and perform the same operation on all of them, creating efficiencies in the processor.

pseudo-code (uncompiled/untested):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i+=16) {
    int16x4x4_t loaded = vld4_s16(int16_arr+i);
    int32x4_t vec1 = vmovl_s16(loaded.val[0]);
    ...
    int32x4_t vec4 = vmovl_s16(loaded.val[3]);
    float32x4x4_t store;
    store.val[0] = vcvtq_f32_s32(vec1);
    ...
    store.val[3] = vcvtq_f32_s32(vec4);
    vst4q_f32(float_arr, store);
}
```

Something like that is likely to be faster.

Useful links:

Neon intrinsics reference: [https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=[Neon]](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=%5BNeon%5D)

Neon programmer's guide [intrinsics section](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0018/a/NEON-Intrinsics/Programming-using-NEON-intrinsics?lang=en) & [loop unrolling](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0018/a/Compiling-NEON-Instructions/Vectorizing-examples/Vectorization-example-on-unrolling-addition-function?lang=en)